# Unable to debug Event Grid Trigger Azure function locally

Tags: azure-functions, azure-eventgrid

I have a simple EventGridTrigger azure function in .net 6(isolated) in visual studo.
Im getting "Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:7071".

```
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.EventGrid;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using Azure.Messaging.EventGrid;

namespace Function
{
    public static class EventGridFunction
    {
        [FunctionName("EventGrid")]
        public static void Run([EventGridTrigger]EventGridEvent eventGridEvent, ILogger log)
        {
            log.LogInformation(eventGridEvent.Data.ToString());
        }
    }
}
```

This is the POST URL Im trying in postman.
http://localhost:7071/runtime/webhooks/EventGrid?functionName=EventGrid

These are the headers.

[image]

Comment: Are you doing any function with eventgrid like send messages event? And what are you trying with that URL? Are you able to debug and run  or not?

Comment: Yes, eventually I will be using this function as a subscription to receive messages from my event grid topic. But now I'm trying to trigger this function to debug them by sending a message from postman.

Answer (score 1):

If anyone else needs help on this - I am using the latest VS 2022 update/template and the port is changed from 7071 to 7125. I discovered this in the launch setting for the project. I tested and localhost:7125 works in Postman. I also believe setting  `FUNCTIONS_HTTPWORKER_PORT` in local.settings.json as suggested here https://github.com/Azure/Azure-Functions/issues/2426 has no effect when running locally.

[image]

Comment: For me it was port 7025 but this answer pointed me in the correct direction.

Answer (score 0):

Even i am facing similar issue like below and i feel this is a bug and raised a [Git-Hub Request](https://github.com/Azure/Azure-Functions/issues/2426) here.

> Yes, eventually I will be using this function as a subscription to receive messages from my event grid topic.

To do this alternatively in local environment , you can follow below approach:

Firstly send the event grid output messages to storage queues like below:

[image]

Then whenever event occurs the a message comes like below(You need to keep separate queue only for event outputs):

[image]

Now, you can use Azure Function Queue trigger, so whenever a message comes in queue , your function triggers.